# What is the most efficient way to whitelist email in PHP?

Tags: php, email, whitelist

i'm a quite beginner in this, and i do my best, but i need some help. I have a question..

i have this code :

```
function prolancemail ( $recipient, $subject, $message, $mailformat = 'default' )
{
    global $configuration, $current_version, $MAIL_CHARSET;

    if ( $mailformat == 'default' )
    {
        $mailformat = $configuration['MAIL_FORMAT'];
    }

    if ( $mailformat == 'text/plain' )
    {
        $headers = 'From: ' . SITENAME . ' <' . $configuration['WEBMASTER_EMAIL'] . '>' . "\r\n" .
        sprintf ( $MAIL_CHARSET, $mailformat );
    }
    elseif ( $mailformat == 'text/html' )
    {
        $headers = 'To: ' . $recipient . "\r\n" .
        'From: ' . SITENAME . ' <' . $configuration['WEBMASTER_EMAIL'] . '>' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHPProLance ' . $current_version . "\r\n" .
        'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
        sprintf ( $MAIL_CHARSET, $mailformat );
    }


    if ( mail ( $recipient, $subject, $message, $headers ) )
    { 
        return true;
    }
    else
    { 
        return false;
    }
```

- i want to add an .vcf attachment(or link with the vcf file) to this function, AND(more important) when the receiver will receive the mail , i want to add a code to this function , that the receiver could whitelisted my email from the vcf file(to add to his contacts), so that, the next mails he will receive from me, will not go to the SPAM mail.
  Any idea?
  all i want is the next mails he will receive from me not to receive in the SPAM folder, and i think that this can be done with whitelist(which i don't know much about) tnx infront.